# What is the best way to acknowledge a reprimand so that it can be removed?

Tags: discussion

It is a bit of an adventure to learn the culture of the different Stack Exchanges that I participate in.

Recently, I received [a polite reprimand](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53972/is-the-omission-of-a-racial-2-to-wisdom-intentional#comment121056_53972) for the manner in which I formatted edits to a question. Upon seeing that, I hopped onto meta, read up on the matter, and consider myself informed.

What I don't know is: what is the most appropriate way to say, "Thanks. Got it. Won't do it again. Shall we remove this comment?" Or is it already the case that moderator comments such as this automatically disappear after a time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hrmm, this is actually trickier than it seems.

We don't see *who* flags comments. From my perspective, either flag it with custom reason saying "Got it." Or leave a comment along those same lines and then flag as obsolete.

Or signal on meta. That works too, though is rather overkill in most cases. It was quite appropriate in this one.

Comment: Awesome. I wasn't sure whether flagging would be too heavy-handed. I appreciate your help, both here and there.

Comment: A new user read meta. You sir, are the one who should be celebrated.